# Insert session data with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, prepared-statement

I've looked around the web an hour or so and I don't know how to solve my problem. The username from $_SESSION['username'] can't be stored in my db in the ways i've tried so I would like some help please. I have a form with inputs from the user and with this data I would like to store the username as well. The table fills with the proper data except the added_by col that only gets a 0 as value. How can I store the username in the DB using prepared statements?

So far this among other combinations have been tried without success.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $trackname = $_POST['trackname'];
   $year = $_POST['year'];
   $trackurl = $_POST['trackurl'];


$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_music (trackname, year, url, added_by) 
VALUES (:trackname, :year, :url, :added_by)");

    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':trackname' => $trackname,
        ':year' => $year,
        ':url' => $trackurl,
        ':added_by' => $_SESSION['username']
));
```

example

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$stmt->bindParam(':trackname', $trackname);
$stmt->bindParam(':year', $year);
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $trackurl);
$stmt->bindParam(':added_by', $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

I can echo the data from $_SESSION['username'] but not store it in the DB.

Comment: What sql error are you getting?

Comment: None as far as i know and can see.

Comment: Try to execute a SQL INSERT without the prepare statement, and see if there is any error.

Comment: Then try add `$DB_con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` before prepare statement, and add `print_r($sth->errorInfo());` after execute try to find if anything wrong

Comment: because your added_by column is an int? Note, you failed to show us your schema

Comment: Nope, no errors only Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) from print_r (changed sth to DB_con/stmt) and the data is stored in the database just as before.

Comment: @Drew ofc....when i build the table my thought was to id the users by id number of int's...sigh. Thank you so much!!! I've spend 3 hours on this. If you put your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: you are most welcome sir. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as requested,

the only chance I see this happening is that your `added_by` column is an int.

Your string goes in, and is converted to an int, making it a zero.